# access tomcat manager from different host

Tags: tomcat8

I have installed tomcat 8 in a linux server.

From another host browser I was able to open the tomcat admin console but not able to open /manager/html.

I have made the changes in tomcat-users.xml and manager.xml and context.html.

```
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
<user username="tomcat" password=“password123" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

In /opt/tomcat8/apache-tomcat-8.5.8/webapps/host-manager

the changes were made in **manager.xml**

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager"
         privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" >

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteHostValve" allow="(*.).abc.corp.company.com"/
>
</Context>
```

I was getting the pop up to enter credentials to log into manager/html but the credentials were not getting validated and I am getting 401 unauthorized error.

Please throw some light.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to acces to manager/html from the same host?

Comment: I am connecting to the machine via SSH , I can't get into the GUI version of that Linux machine to check. Is there a way to check ?

Comment: Yes, yet a little complicated: Running a command-line HTTP client, like cUrl, or an Ant script, or a Java program.

Answer (score 0):

(Maybe a shot to the air, but...)

Check your tomcat-users.xml format: The double-quote after `password=` is a typographical quote, not a standard quote.

Comment: I have added the quotes again in tomcat-users.xml , quotes resembles the same

Comment: Have you read carefully the Tomcat's log file? No previous errors found?

Comment: Thank you for your excellent observation Santi , I have recreated tomcat-users.xml and after restart it worked. Thank you so much for your help.